# python how to speed up on query huge amount of data?

Tags: python, postgresql

My task is: selecting the data from two large tables and do some operations on it.

During testing, I find that the query time takes really long.

Time taken : 800secs, TableA row count = 1.8M, TableB row count = 3.8M

I need the program can finish it within 300secs.

What I did:

1. Use named cursor (use less memory, but no time difference)
2. Use threading on selecting tables part (no time difference)
3. Use fetchmany instead of simply looping the cursor (no time difference)
4. Separate the query by `created`, run several python in the same time (speeded up 20% after I split it into 2 parts, no more significant change even I increase the part number to 3,4,5....)

```
E.g.
python main.py --created_start=1635343080000 --created_end=1635343140000 --process_id=0 &
python main.py --created_start=1635343140000 --created_end=1635343200000 --process_id=1 & 
...
```

Part of my code:

```
...
    cur_a = connection.cursor(name=f'fetch_a_{args.process_id}')
    cur_a.execute(
                    f"""
                    SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE created BETWEEN {args.created_start} AND {args.created_end}
                    """
            )
    cur_b = connection.cursor(name=f'fetch_b_{args.process_id}')
    cur_b.execute(
                    f"""
                    SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE created BETWEEN {args.created_start} AND {args.created_end}
                    """
            )

    def query_to_set(cur, table_name, table_set, table_pk):
        step_size = 20000
        _fetched_size = 0
        while True:
            rows = cur.fetchmany(size=step_size)
            if not rows:
                break
            _fetched_size += len(rows)
            print(f"selecting {table_name} data...{_fetched_size} fetched")


    #query form DB is a IO-bound task, use multithreading 
    x = threading.Thread(
        target=query_to_set,
        args=(cur_a, "tableA")
    )
    x.start()

    y = threading.Thread(
        target=query_to_set,
        args=(cur_b, "tableB"),
    )
    y.start()

    x.join()
    y.join()
```

Edit 1:
I have changed the following and it reduces the process time drastically

1. DO NOT `select *`, select only the fields you need
2. Place your program near your DB. i.e. If your DB is on AWS, place your program in AWS machine

Edit 2:

```
EXPLAIN select * from tableA where created between 1635343080000 and 1635343200000;


Index Scan using tableA_created_idx on tableA(cost=0.58..229971.15 rows=5000000 width=114)
  Index Cond: ((created >= '1635343080000'::bigint) AND (created <= '1635343200000'::bigint))
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to know how much time the query takes.  Can you run the query by hand with explain analyze and show us the results?  Also, how many rows are you selecting from the table?  Can you perform your operations in the database instead of in python?

Comment: Edited. I think the SQL is quite optimised as its a simple select statement

Answer (score 2):

Did you already created indexes on your postgres tables ? Creating the right indexes in line with your queries should improve the performance dramatically. In your case, you may create a `BTREE` index on the column `created` in both tables tableA and tableB.

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS tableA_created;
CREATE INDEX tableA_created
  ON tableA
  USING btree (created) ;
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS tableB_created;
CREATE INDEX tableB_created
  ON tableB
  USING btree (created) ;
```

Then you could try to replace the cursor in python by a `JOIN` query between `tableA` and `tableB` in postgres.